# SMB Share (samba) Centos 6 Mounted hard drive Permission Denied

Tags: linux, centos, samba, server-message-block, ext4

I have set up a SMB share on Centos for all users. This share is available and working correctly. 
Guide followed -> [CentOS 6.4 Samba Standalone Server With tdbsam Backend](http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-6.4-samba-standalone-server-with-tdbsam-backend)

Procedure:

For diagnostic purposes I have Disabled SELINUX and iptables (disabled selinux in config file then rebooted machine)

```
//Disbale iptables
service iptables stop

//set runlevel on smb
chkconfig --levels 235 smb on
/etc/init.d/smb start

//Create folder and set file permissions for share
mkdir -p /home/shares/allusers
chown -R root:users /home/shares/allusers/
chmod -R ug+rwx,o+rx-w /home/shares/allusers/
```

Config added to smb.conf

```
[allusers]
    comment = All Users
    path = /home/shares/allusers
    valid users = @users
    force group = users
    create mask - 0660
    directory mask = 0771
    writable = yes
```

Restart samba

```
//Restart samba
service smb restart
```

Add User

```
//Add user
useradd <username> -m -G users

//Set password for user
passwd <username>

//Set samba password
smbpasswd -a <username>
```

In this scenario the share is available and working correctly. However if I try this exact process on an ext4 partition mounted under /mnt/mediaHardDrive the share shows in an smb browser, but is unavailable. It appears the authentication is not correct.

Any suggestions?

---------- EDIT ----------

Curiously, if I mount the ext4 partition within the /home/shares/allusers directory, the hard drive is assessable.

Ideally this is not how I would like to do this, so if anyone has any suggestions they will be gratefully received.